# Scan dynamodb table based on filter which is not present in all object

Tags: node.js, dynamodb-queries, aws-sdk-js, amazon-dynamodb

So I'm trying to filter my dynamoDb data based on role as you can see role attribute is present in some of the objects not in all

```
[
  {
    id: "7",
    email: 'test1@gmail.com',
    name: 'test1',
    age: '12',
  },
  {
    id: "8",
    email: 'test2@gmail.com',
    name: 'test2',
    age: '12',
  },
  {
    email: 'test3@gmail.com',
    name: 'test3',
    age: '12',
    test: 'test',
    role: 'ADMIN'
  },
  {
    email: 'test4@gmail.com',
    name: 'test4',
    age: '12',
    test: 'test',
    role: 'ADMIN'
  }
]
```

if I try to scan with **email** it works but if I try to scan with **role** its gives me error:
**Invalid FilterExpression: Attribute name is a reserved keyword; reserved keyword: role**

I tried with code

```
let params = {
  TableName: 'tableName',
  FilterExpression: 'role =:role',
  ExpressionAttributeValues: { ':role': 'ADMIN' },
  expressionAttributeNames: { '#role': 'role' }
}
let result = await this.docClient.scan(params).promise();
```

and this

```
let params = {
  TableName: 'tableName',
  FilterExpression: 'attribute_not_exists(role)',
  ExpressionAttributeValues: { ':role': 'ADMIN' },
  expressionAttributeNames: { '#role': 'role' }
}
let result = await this.docClient.scan(params).promise();
```

both giving me same error

Comment: It's a reserved keyword, so you can't use it. You could use `'#r = :role'` for the filter expression and `'#r':'role'` for the names mapping. Also typo: expressionAttributeNames.

Comment: thanks its works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you had a typo in your first code snippet. `FilterExpression: 'role =:role',` should be `FilterExpression: '#role =:role',`.

So the following should work,

```
let params = {
  TableName: 'tableName',
  FilterExpression: '#role =:role',
  ExpressionAttributeValues: { ':role': 'ADMIN' },
  ExpressionAttributeNames: { '#role': 'role' }
}
let result = await this.docClient.scan(params).promise();
```